# Need Help: "IntelliSense: data member initializer is not allowed"

Tags: c++, intellisense, directx-11

First post here so sorry if things are wrong.
I have been following a tutorial on C++ & directx11 and I have come up with an error that does not replicate in the tutorial. The sample code is in a header i have created. 
In the "private: " section all 3 lines of code give the error "IntelliSense: data member initializer is not allowed".

```
#pragma once
#include "Window.h"
#include <d3d11.h>

class Renderer 
{
public:
    Renderer(Window& window);

private:
    //Errors here
    IDXGISwapChain* m_SwapChain = nullptr;
    ID3D11Device* m_device = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* m_deviceContext = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes intellisense is wrong.  Does it compile?

Comment: If I recall correctly a default initialization in that way is only allowed as of C++11. Can you show us how you compile your code?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [C++ data member initializer is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936009/c-data-member-initializer-is-not-allowed)

Comment: The duplicate is old, and things have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize data members in a class definition. The correct way to do it is in the CPP file:

```
IDXGISwapChain* Renderer::m_SwapChain = nullptr;
ID3D11Device* Renderer::m_device = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext* Renderer::m_deviceContext = nullptr;
```

You could also do it in your constructor, like so:

```
Renderer::Renderer(Window& window) :
    m_SwapChain(nullptr),
    m_device(nullptr),
    m_deviceContext(nullptr)
{
    // Initialization code here
}
```

I prefer the latter.

Comment: Actually you can in C++11 and higher: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19087ed32a3c0bdd

Comment: But obviously not in the compiler the OP is using.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  Sometimes intellisense gives an error but the code still compiles.  Since this post is just tagged with C++ we should answer with respect to the current standard at the time of asking.

Comment: Not necessarily. Inteillisense is a separate compiler from the one Visual Studio uses to compile your code.

Comment: Point taken. I call it "Intellidense".